# При работе с keras выдает ошибку: ValueError: None values not supported

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, keras

Столкнулся со странной проблемой в keras. При работе с ИНС, которая ранее была работоспособна, при тех же данных python стал выдавать ошибку. Код не менялся ранее, однако, сейчас не работает.
Версии 
tensorflow:2.1.0
keras:2.3.1

Код:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy
    import numpy as np
    import keras as kr
    import tensorflow as tn
    from pathlib import Path
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from keras import Sequential
    from keras.layers import *
    from keras.regularizers import l2, l1
    from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
    from keras.models import save_model, load_model
    from keras import regularizers
    from keras import optimizers
    import matplotlib as mpl
    numpy.random.seed(42)
    def get_data(path, test_size=0.3):
        data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in Path(path).glob('*.csv')],
                         ignore_index=True).values
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        x, y = scaler.fit_transform(data[:, 1:]), data[:, [0]]
        return train_test_split(x, y, test_size=test_size)

    path = r'D:\path'
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = \
        get_data(path, test_size=0.15)

    model_fn = str(Path(path) / 'model.h5')
    early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_mean_squared_error', min_delta=0.01,
                               patience=20, verbose=1, mode='auto')
    chkpt = ModelCheckpoint(model_fn, 
                            monitor='val_mean_squared_error', 
                            verbose=1, 
                            save_best_only=True, 
                            mode='auto')
    callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=39999, activation="relu",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(150, input_dim=39999, activation="relu",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(120, input_dim=39999, activation="relu",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=39999, activation="relu",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(1))
    #
    Adelta = optimizers.Adadelta(lr=2.5, rho=0, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
    model.compile( optimizer=Adelta, loss="mse", metrics=['mae','mse'])
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=60, batch_size=30, 
                     verbose=1,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

Текст ошибки:

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6b227647f07b> in <module>

      1 history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=60, batch_size=30, 
      2                  verbose=1,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
----> 3                 callbacks=callbacks)

> *Здесь еще полотно текста с отссылками на tensorflow*

>ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Ошибка возникает когда я запускаю обучение сети.
Ссылка на фрагмент данных для воспроизведения ошибки https://yadi.sk/d/EuvIYiBZjSYNMg

Comment: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (39999,) but got array with shape (178,)` возникает раньше из-за ошибки в размерностях

Comment: Заменил данные по ссылке. Для контроля прикрепил вывод формата, который я получил и использую в работе. 
print (x_train.shape)
print (y_train.shape)
print (x_test.shape)
print (y_test.shape)
(456, 39999)
(456, 1)
(81, 39999)
(81, 1)

Comment: вы хотите сказать что у вас раньше этот код работал без ошибок??? У вас явные ошибки в размерностях слоев - не представляю как эта модель могла работать раньше

Comment: Блин, опять не те данные. Мои извинения. Обновил ссылку. 
Однако, результаты я получал. Ваш комментарий меня огорошил, если честно =)

Comment: Проблему решил. Можно закрыть тему. Спасибо за уделенное время.